# What type of string is best to use for Win32 and DirectX?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, directx-10

I am in the process of developing a small game in DirectX 10 and C++ and I'm finding it hell with the various different types of strings that are required for the various different directx / win32 function calls.

Can anyone recommend which of the various strings are available are the best to use, ideally it would be one type of string that gives a good cast to the other types (LPCWSTR and LPCSTR mostly). Thus far I have been using std::string and std::wstring and doing the .c_str() function to get it in to the correct format.

I would like to get just 1 type of string that I use to pass in to all functions and then doing the cast inside the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::wstring` with `c_str()` exactly as you have been doing. I see no reason to use `std::string` on Windows, your code may as well always use the native UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: This works fine but I am finding it difficult to find how to cast between std::wstring and LPCSTR as doing it through c_str() doesn't work.

Comment: I'd simply stop calling ANSI functions. Only call Unicode functions. If you simply have to do so then obtain or write converter functions that convert between `string` and `wstring`.

Comment: Unfortunately the DirectX10 API's don't allow me this comfort. A number of objects returned by D3D Calls only take ANSI values, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205706(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Looking at that API, it seems like the input parameters may not be variables in your program. If so then just declare them as `const char* MyTechniqueName = "...."`. For such an API, since it cannot receive Unicode text I think you should store the value in your program as ANSI. No point there storing as Unicode and converting since the conversion may fail. So use `wstring` where a Unicode API is available, otherwise use `string`.

Comment: You can use an instance of `std::wstring_convert` to easily convert `wstring` to a `string` and then use `c_str()`. `convert(my_wstring).to_bytes().c_str()`.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick to `std::wstring` as well. If you really need to pass `std::string` somewhere, you can still convert it on the fly:

```
std::string s = "Hello, World";
std::wstring ws(s.begin(), s.end());
```

It works the other way around as well.

Comment: Pity I can't mark multiple answers as correct as this is certainly not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Native COM (the stuff of `#import <type_library>`), then `_bstr_t`. It natively typecasts to both LPCWSTR and LPCSTR, and it meshes nicely with COM's memory allocation model. No need for `.c_str()` calls.

Comment: Again same pity I can't mark multiple answers correct, although as this is for a university assignment they aren't too keen on us using COM. Thanks,

Comment: DirectX *is* COM-based. You cannot help it. For the rest of Win32, `wstring` will do, but specifically for DirectX, you better have a COM-friendly string.

Comment: @Seva DX doesn't have a lot of methods with `BSTR` parameters IIRC